# How to get the "data" fromphp array in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My code in ajax.

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'url.php',
       dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(data)
      {
         id  = // I want to get the ID data
      }
  });
```

In my (data) there's already a different data in it one of that data is the ID. What I want to do is get the ID data and save it to a variable.

Here's my PHP :

```
$comments = array();
$get = "Some query";
    $result = $connection->query($get);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
           $comments[] = $row;

    }
 echo json_encode($comments);
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter "data" will be the response printed by url.php script. It depends on how you are printing the information from PHP script.
If you print it as a json like `{'id': 'some_id'}`, then the "id" var can be fetched using `data.id` on your script.

But if you are just printing text, then "data" parameter will be the printed characters from url.php.

To help you more, you can post what you have inside url.php script.

Comment: See improved post above. Ill wait for your reply sir

Comment: Do you have a valid json example for the line "echo json_encode($comments);"? What does it print out for you?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're expecting the response to be a json object, since you set dataType to 'JSON'. So for example if your php script returns something like that:

`<?php $result['data'] = $yourdata; $result['id'] =$id; echo json_encode($result); ?>`

Then you can use the result on the client side like this:

`success: function(result)
      {
         id  = result.id;
         data = result.data;
      }`